# Reference Error 1056 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have googled and figured out the issue with my current problem is that I have the `Automatically Declare Stage Instances` box unchecked. The problem is that I can't figure out what I need to add to make it work properly, any help would be great.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property btnTwo on Main.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean with the "declare stage instances" unchecked? You need to declare them as *public* variables with the same name as the instance name on the stage (as far as I know! :) ).